# Check if ListView is empty in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there a way to check if ListView is empty.

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: _items.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return _buildFilteredItem(context, index);
  },
)
```

I want to search through my items and if its empty show a Text widget saying no items found. _buildFilteredItem returns null if the item could not be found.

Answer (score 42):

Check `_items` before creating `ListView`

```
return _items.isEmpty ? Center(child: Text('Empty')) : ListView.builder(
  itemCount: _items.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return _buildFilteredItem(context, index);
  },
)
```

Comment: what if the _items is null?

Comment: If it can be `null` - you may change `_items.isEmpty` to `(_items?.isEmpty ?? true)`

Comment: I can't use your above commented code, i have the same Listview.builder to check the list items are null or empty. more errors are pops up.

Comment: locations == null ? Center(child: Text('Empty')) : ListView.builder() seems to be works

Comment: In you example you're checking only for `null` not for `empty`. And for empty list you'll get empty screen without placeholder. Could you describe what errors are popping up?

Answer (score -2):

To check for empty list the you can do

```
ListView.builder(
   itemCount:_items.length, 
   builder:(context, index){ 
      _items.length==0
      ?return Center(child:Text("List is empty"))
      :return _buildFilteredItem(context, index);})
```

Comment: List builder won't build the widget at all if the item list is empty